# Why does JavaScript get this comparison wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is happening on an angular application I'm building. If a user enters 80 into an HTML input, it always seems to get this comparison wrong.

```
var x = '80';
var y = 150.9800;

/* Returns incorrect answer */
if (parceFloat(x) < y) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Is the method name `parceFloat` or `parseFloat`?

Comment: What is `parceFloat`?

Comment: because there is a typo?

Comment: Typo is there... use parseFloat(x) instead parceFloat(x)

Comment: Is there a typo or something?

Comment: Find out what it is exactly by looking into console because if that is a typo then it should throw an error instead of a boolean value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parceFloat()` is not a function, the function is `parseFloat()`

A simple typo is all the error there is.

Comment: Please do not answer typo questions, flag for closure instead.

Comment: Noted. Will Do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Par**s**eFloat() not par**c**eFloat() ...
parceFloat is not an existing function.

Comment: Please do not answer typo questions, flag for closure instead.